# Resetting UI on the viewport

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I downloaded a blender file from online, and all the menues like "view" "select" "pose" options are at the bottom, when they were normally at the top. Is there a way to reset all these UIs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on a menu item and select Header -> Flip to Top to restore the menu to the top.  If everything is all messed up, you can just add a new default workspace by hitting the + button at the end of all of the selectable workspaces at the top of the window and choosing the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Blender files save the user interface used by the person who created the file, but you can bypass that and use the file with your usual layout.

Open blender, go to *File* > *Open* and choose the file you want to open, press <kbd>N</kbd> (or press the gear icon on the top right of the window) to open the options for loading the file and de-select "load UI", that way the user interface saved on the file will not be used.

[image]