# How do I reset all of my view panels without having to do the click and drag method?

Tags: customization

I would like to find a different solution to closing these windows without having to do the click and drag.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/822/how-do-you-return-to-the-default-view-the-one-you-see-when-blender-starts

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165915/67327 this is the answer that cleared everything up for me as far as controlling viewports

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203138/resetting-ui-on-the-viewport/203139

Answer (score 2):

If you want to come back to the default windows setup you can click on the "+" tab on the top and choose *General > Layout* (or whatever setup you want to come back to). You can move or delete all this tabs with right click. If you want to save your own custom layout I think you need to create it and *Save the Startup File*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Stop modifying the windows and use **Layouts** or [**Workspaces**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/workspaces.html) instead.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Page Down</kbd> to  navigate to the next layout.

It is much faster, and you can set your own set of screens for specific tasks, and to suit your personal workflow, without modifying the interface at all or dragging windows everytime.

Start with an empty project. Use the plus sign at the top to create a new workspace.

Arrange the windows to the way you want to work.

Create as many layouts/workspaces as you want.

Once you've created your own layouts in an empty project, save the project as default (*File* > *Defaults* > *Save Strartup File*), and then your custom layouts will be available to you every time you open blender.

To open an existing project into your new layout use *File* > *Open* and disable the *Load UI* option, so that the file opens with your default User Interface and not the one saved on the file.

For more detail read the following link:

[Can screen layouts or workspaces be locked?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-or-workspaces-be-locked/34183?).