# properties , preferences or outliner areas do not display

Tags: interface

[image]going from viewport to Properties, or preferences or outliner I get a full black screen of properties, preferences, or outlier but nothing more

Comment: Please add an image of your Blender window via the Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: image has been added

Comment: It looks as if you've extended the Outliner to fullscreen. Try hovering over it and pressing CTRL-Space. If that doesn't work read through https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208221/how-do-i-reset-all-of-my-view-panels-without-having-to-do-the-click-and-drag-met