# Outliner / properties etc dissapeared

Tags: 3d-view, outliner

This happened to me a couple times before, where i accidently click a key combination and it hides the outliner + other panels

Pressing CTRL UP / DOWN / LEFT / RIGHT does not bring anything back for me.

And restarting blender doesn't help..

[image]

Comment: How about CTRL- SPACE?

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. CTRL + Space doesn't do anything for me

Comment: Try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160129/reload-interface-while-keeping-data   _ie_ open a new file,  then open this one but don't load the UI.  After which look in the view menu > area .. ctlr -space and ctrl alt space are general shortcuts that maximize an area. Yours may be different.

Comment: Alright man, thanks. still think it's weird you can't just restore with the same hotkey that messed it up in the first place :(

Comment: Another thing to try,  is to right click on modelling tab and delete. Then on + at far right of tabs open default > modelling again.  Would say can restore, it's just a matter of which hotkey.

Comment: Since you are starting with blender don't start with the bad habt of modifying the interface so many times. Instead, create layouts or workspaces that work for your own personal workflow and stop messing around with the interface.  Read: [how do I reset my view panels](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208223/92768) and [Resetting UI on the viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203138/resetting-ui-on-the-viewport/203141#203141)

Answer (score 1):

What you have basically done is destroyed all areas except the 3-D view editor. Thankfully, you can easily bring them back by dragging the corners of the area to split it, then changing the new area to what you need (see the blender manual on “User interface”), or like one of the commenters said, you can open a new blend file, then open this one without loading its UI.